# Issue with control package on Python

Tags: python, controls

I recently downloaded the python-control package, since I want to simulate the response of a discrete-time transfer function in a MIMO system. To make it work for this kind of system I also had to install the slycot package, which I installed from a binary wheel. The issues happens when I try to use the function `forced_response()`, from which I only get zeros as a response.

I tried an example I found on the internet and I got the same result (only zeros). Therefore, I do not think the problem has anything to do with my code.

I also get this messages:

Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chetrs_rook
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_dsyev_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_dsyev_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_dsyev_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work...
...    Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_cggbak
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_cggbak
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work
Wrong parameter 1 in LAPACKE_chbevd_2stage_work

But I have found nothing about it.